# Partially fill a CAShapeLayer() with a colour

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, bounding-box

I am working with swift on xcode 9.2 to create bounding boxes on iOS 11. What I have here is a bounding box that can either be completely clear (so that the object being bounded can be seen) or completely filled with color (green here, so that the object the box bounds is completely covered in green). What I would like to do, is go partway with the color fill so that the bounding box is translucent. For instance, a bounding box with a green tint where the object being bounded is still visible. Any help on how to accomplish this will be very helpful

```
class BoundingBox {
  let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer
  let textLayer: CATextLayer

  init() {
    shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    //shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayer.isHidden = true

    textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textLayer.isHidden = true
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    textLayer.fontSize = 14
    textLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: textLayer.fontSize)
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
  }
```

The .fillColor property on line 6 and 7 is what I am currently manipulating to change the bounding box properties

Comment: I think you're just asking to set the *alpha", as in `UIColor(red:, green:, blue:, alpha:)`. Have you tried this?

Comment: That did it, thank you!